# How to add a grid to a shape file in R?

Tags: r

I have several shapefiles and I need to add a square grid for everyone. Something like this:

[image]

https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/178-map-with-grid-cartography-pkg/

Is there any package or reference where I can start learning?

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations for books/software/examples are off-topic for StackOverflow, so this question will probably be closed. However, the link you've got *IS* a reference where you can start learning. It tells you how to make the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the package [`map`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maps/index.html). At that point you have dataframes that contain longitudes and latitudes of different states and countries. You join that data with your dataframe containing your metric of interest and then you plot everything with something like:

```
library(ggplot2)
your_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(LONG, LAT, fill = your_metric, group = STATEID)) +
     geom_polygon(colour = "white") +
     scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red", limit = c(0, 100))
```

Start from [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/map_data.html)